# What jolt spec will be required to get the desired output

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I have a JSON input data where *author* and *publisher* tags have IDs only and their complete info is given under *relationships* tag. I need these IDs to be replaced with actual data in the output JSON.

Is it doable via JOLT transformation?

I tried many combinations and read their Javadoc but no luck so far. I can do it with little tweak in java code & jolt transformation, but want to do it via JOLT transformation only so that no new jar files need to be created.

I have a sample input JSON like below

```
  "meta": {
    "total": 3
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1112245810",
      "title": "Introduction to JavaScript Object Notation",
      "author": "54256",
      "publisher": "57756",
      "edition": "first",
      "published": "2012"
    },
    {
      "id": "1156464683",
      "title": "JSON at Work",
      "author": "15467",
      "publisher": "57756",
      "edition": "second",
      "published": "2014"
    },
    {
      "id": "1004467968",
      "title": "A Tiny Bit Mortal",
      "author": "54256",
      "publisher": "56465",
      "edition": "first",
      "published": "2018"
    }
  ],
  "relationships": [
    {
      "id": "54256",
      "type": "author",
      "attributes": {
        "first-name": "Lindsay",
        "last-name": "Bassett",
        "city": "Michigan"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "15467",
      "type": "author",
      "attributes": {
        "first-name": "Tom",
        "last-name": "Marrs",
        "city": "Cologne"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "57756",
      "type": "publisher",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "O'REILLY",
        "established": "1984"
      }
    },
     {
      "id": "56465",
      "type": "publisher",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "APRESS",
        "established": "1979"
      }
    }
    ]
}
```

and the desired output JSON needed

```
{
  "meta": {
    "total": 3
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1112245810",
      "title": "Introduction to JavaScript Object Notation",
      "author": {
        "first-name": "Lindsay",
        "last-name": "Bassett",
        "city": "Michigan"
      },
      "publisher": {
        "name": "O'REILLY",
        "established": "1984"
      },
      "edition": "first",
      "published": "2012"
    },
    {
      "id": "1156464683",
      "title": "JSON at Work",
      "author": {
        "first-name": "Tom",
        "last-name": "Marrs",
        "city": "Cologne"
      },
      "publisher": {
        "name": "O'REILLY",
        "established": "1984"
      },
      "edition": "second",
      "published": "2014"
    },
    {
      "id": "1004467968",
      "title": "A Tiny Bit Mortal",
      "author": {
        "first-name": "Lindsay",
        "last-name": "Bassett",
        "city": "Michigan"
      },
      "publisher": {
        "name": "APRESS",
        "established": "1979"
      },
      "edition": "first",
      "published": "2018"
    }
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces the desired result (and possibly could be refactored further).

The main idea around it is setting the JSON to be keyed by something it can then be "joined" by. See the outputs of each shift and brief explantion below.

**Full Spec**

```
[
  {
    //shift 1
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "relationships": {
        "*": {
          "type": {
            "*": {
              "@(2,attributes)": "@2.@(3,id)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    //shift 2
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "author": {
            "*": {
              "@(2)": "data.@2.data.[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    //shift 3
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "author": {
        "*": {
          "@": "data.&.author"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    //shift 4
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "data": {
            "*": {
              "@(id)": "data.@(id).id",
              "@(title)": "data.@(id).title",
              "@(2,author)": "data.@(id).author",
              "@(publisher)": "data.@(id).publisher",
              "@(edition)": "data.@(id).edition",
              "@(published)": "data.@(id).published"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    //shift 5
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "publisher": {
            "*": {
              "@(2)": "data.@2.data.[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    //shift 6
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "publisher": {
        "*": {
          "@": "data.&.publisher"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    //shift 7
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "data": {
            "*": {
              "@(id)": "data.@(id).id",
              "@(title)": "data.@(id).title",
              "@(author)": "data.@(id).author",
              "@(2,publisher)": "data.@(id).publisher",
              "@(edition)": "data.@(id).edition",
              "@(published)": "data.@(id).published"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    //shift 8
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "@": "data.[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Shift 1**

Relationships keyed by there respective IDs:

```
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "relationships": {
        "*": {
          "type": {
            "*": {
              "@(2,attributes)": "@2.@(3,id)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```
// ...
  "author" : {
    "54256" : {
      "first-name" : "Lindsay",
      "last-name" : "Bassett",
      "city" : "Michigan"
    },
    "15467" : {
      "first-name" : "Tom",
      "last-name" : "Marrs",
      "city" : "Cologne"
    }
  },
  "publisher" : {
    "57756" : {
      "name" : "O'REILLY",
      "established" : "1984"
    },
    "56465" : {
      "name" : "APRESS",
      "established" : "1979"
    }
  }
}
```

**Shift 2 and 5**

Data keyed by there author (2) or publisher (5) respective IDs:

```
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "author": {
        //"publisher": {
            "*": {
              "@(2)": "data.@2.data.[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```
  "data" : {
    "54256" : {
      "data" : [ {
        "id" : "1112245810",
        "title" : "Introduction to JavaScript Object Notation",
        "author" : "54256",
        "publisher" : "57756",
        "edition" : "first",
        "published" : "2012"
      }, {
        "id" : "1004467968",
        "title" : "A Tiny Bit Mortal",
        "author" : "54256",
        "publisher" : "56465",
        "edition" : "first",
        "published" : "2018"
      } ]
    },
    "15467" : {
      "data" : [ {
        "id" : "1156464683",
        "title" : "JSON at Work",
        "author" : "15467",
        "publisher" : "57756",
        "edition" : "second",
        "published" : "2014"
      } ]
    }
  },
```

**Shift 3 and 6**

Now move author (3) or publisher (6) to be next to the data:

```
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "author": {
    //"publisher": {
        "*": {
          "@": "data.&.author"
        //"@": "data.&.publisher"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

```
   "54256" : {
      "data" : [ {
        "id" : "1112245810",
        "title" : "Introduction to JavaScript Object Notation",
        "author" : "54256",
        "publisher" : "57756",
        "edition" : "first",
        "published" : "2012"
      }, {
        "id" : "1004467968",
        "title" : "A Tiny Bit Mortal",
        "author" : "54256",
        "publisher" : "56465",
        "edition" : "first",
        "published" : "2018"
      } ],
      "author" : {
        "first-name" : "Lindsay",
        "last-name" : "Bassett",
        "city" : "Michigan"
      }
    },
    "15467" : {
```

**Spec 4 and 7**

Copy authors (4) or publisher (7) to each data element and key by data ID:

```
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "data": {
            "*": {
              "@(id)": "data.@(id).id",
              "@(title)": "data.@(id).title",
              "@(2,author)": "data.@(id).author",
            //"@(author)": "data.@(id).author",
              "@(publisher)": "data.@(id).publisher",
            //"@(2,publisher)": "data.@(id).publisher",
              "@(edition)": "data.@(id).edition",
              "@(published)": "data.@(id).published"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

```
"data" : {
    "1112245810" : {
      "id" : "1112245810",
      "title" : "Introduction to JavaScript Object Notation",
      "author" : {
        "first-name" : "Lindsay",
        "last-name" : "Bassett",
        "city" : "Michigan"
      },
      "publisher" : "57756",
      "edition" : "first",
      "published" : "2012"
    },
    "1004467968" : {
      "id" : "1004467968",
      "title" : "A Tiny Bit Mortal",
      "author" : {
        "first-name" : "Lindsay",
        "last-name" : "Bassett",
        "city" : "Michigan"
      },
      "publisher" : "56465",
      "edition" : "first",
      "published" : "2018"
    },
```

**Spec 8**

Remove data id as key:

```
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "@": "data.[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```
  "data" : [ {
    "id" : "1112245810",
    "title" : "Introduction to JavaScript Object Notation",
    "author" : {
      "first-name" : "Lindsay",
      "last-name" : "Bassett",
      "city" : "Michigan"
    },
    "publisher" : {
      "name" : "O'REILLY",
      "established" : "1984"
    },
    "edition" : "first",
    "published" : "2012"
  }, {
    "id" : "1156464683",
```

Comment: Thanks @Matthew. You have no idea how much time I'd spent on this.